# hide attributes in Laravel API Resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection, laravel-api

I want to hide an attribute in the Collection API Resource
I don't want to do it always, so I need something like `makeHidden()` to do it when I want.

But API Resource return `Illuminate\Support\Collection` instance that has not `makeHidden()` method
the Eloquent Collection Class is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize a response for some case, you could create a second Resource class that will only contain your desired attributes:

```php
class FirstResource extends JsonResource {

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'first_value' => $this->first_value,
            'second_value' => $this->second_value,
            'third_value' => $this->third_value,
            'fourth_value' => $this->fourth_value,
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
class SecondResource extends JsonResource {

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'first_value' => $this->first_value,
            'second_value' => $this->second_value,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then use them whenever you need one of them:

```php
public function aControllerMethod()
{
    $model = MyModel::find($id);

    return new FirstResource($model);
}
```

```php
public function anotherControllerMethod()
{
    $model = MyModel::find($id);

    return new SecondResource($model);
}
```

Now you will have two different responses from the same model (or collection).